# How to style a CSS Grid row?

Tags: css, css-grid

I know that it's not possible to style the Grid row or column itself as it is just implicit construct and the HTML elements that built a particular row or column can only be styled.

I'm wondering how to add an HTML item as a "background" of few other HTML elements that built each row, in order to add one `box-shadow` for each row. Is there any way to make it witout workarounds and without specifying `grid-column` and `grid-row` manually for each grid item *(as in 2nd example below)*?

Edit:
I also have to admit that I want to add multiple rows dinamically so it's impossible to specify each element position in the grid layout manually.

```css
.list{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
  grid-auto-rows: 3em;
  grid-row-gap: .5em;
  margin: 2em;
  padding: .2em;
  width: 360px;
}

.list .grid-shadow{
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 4px rgba(220,220,220);
  grid-column: span 4;
}

.manual span:nth-child(1){
  grid-column: 1 / span 4;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.manual span:nth-child(2){
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
}
.manual span:nth-child(3){
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1;
}
.manual span:nth-child(4){
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 1;
}
.manual span:nth-child(5){
  grid-column: 1 / span 4;
  grid-row: 2;
}
.manual span:nth-child(6){
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2;
}
.manual span:nth-child(7){
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 2;
}
.manual span:nth-child(8){
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 2;
}
```

```html
<h2>I want the items with data to be placed "within" the shadowed element</h2>
<div class="list">
  <span class="grid-shadow"></span>
  <span>John</span>
  <span>Doe</span>
  <span>john.doe@gmail.com</span>
  <span class="grid-shadow"></span>
  <span>Susane</span>
  <span>Simpson</span>
  <span>s.simpson@gmail.com</span>
</div>

<h2>How it should look like:</h2>
<div class="list manual">
  <span class="grid-shadow"></span>
  <span>John</span>
  <span>Doe</span>
  <span>john.doe@gmail.com</span>
  <span class="grid-shadow"></span>
  <span>Susane</span>
  <span>Simpson</span>
  <span>s.simpson@gmail.com</span>
</div>
```

Comment: does `span.grid-shadow` have to be inside of `div.list` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

absolute and a pseudo might be enough here :

```css
.list {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
  grid-auto-rows: 3em;
  grid-row-gap: .5em;
  margin: 2em;
  padding: .2em;
  width: 360px;
  position: relative;
}

.list span:nth-child(3n + 1):before {
  content: '';
  height: 3em;/* matching row template */
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 4px rgba(220,220,220);
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <span>John</span>
  <span>Doe</span>
  <span>john.doe@gmail.com</span>

  <span>Susane</span>
  <span>Simpson</span>
  <span>s.simpson@gmail.com</span>
  
</div>
```

Comment: the one disadvantage is that i have to rely on absolute height values, but eventually it's the only reasonable solution for now. thank you

Comment: @Paweł these are from your  `grid-auto-rows: 3em;` , to make it easier to manage, you could use a var() CSS . `.list {--rowHeight: 3em; grid-auto-rows: var(--rowHeight);} .list span:nth-child(3n + 1):before { height: var(--rowHeight);}`  ;)

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution with `clip-path`.

```css
.list{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
  grid-auto-rows: 3em;
  grid-row-gap: 2em;
  grid-column-gap: 0px;
  margin: 2em;
  padding: .2em;
  width: 380px;
}

.list>*{
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 4px grey;
}

.list>*:nth-child(3n+1){ /*left of row*/
  clip-path: polygon(-50% -50%, -50% 150%, 100% 150%, 100% -50%);
}

.list>*:nth-child(3n){ /*right of row*/
  clip-path: polygon(0% -50%, 0% 150%, 150% 150%, 150% -50%);
}

.list>*:not(:nth-child(3n+1)):not(:nth-child(3n)){ /*middle of row*/
  clip-path: polygon(0% -50%, 0% 150%, 100% 150%, 100% -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <span>John</span>
  <span>Doe</span>
  <span>john.doe@gmail.com</span>
  <span>Susane</span>
  <span>Simpson</span>
  <span>s.simpson@gmail.com</span>
</div>
```